# Why is this set of parser combinators overflowing the stack?

Tags: scala, stack-overflow, parser-combinators, ebnf

#### TL;DR

My parser-combinators for EBNF grammar specs overflows the stack. Why? How do I fix it?

#### Background

I'm attempting to define a parser via combinators from the scala library for an [EBNF syntax](http://matt.might.net/articles/grammars-bnf-ebnf/). In actuality, the code builds an AST of the grammar, but I've stripped out those bits and inlined a utility method in order to produce an MVCE (below).

#### Problem

The code as written, when run, gives a stack overflow (also below). What I cannot get my head around is that it seems to overflow in the skip whitespace part of the parsing. How do I resolve this error? It would really be unfortunate if parsing EBNF syntax isn't possible—I intend to develop some tooling for it.

#### MVCE

```scala
package org.benknoble.ebnf

import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

class EbnfParserSimple extends RegexParsers {

  def nonterminal: Parser[String] = """<[^>]+>""".r

  def goesTo: Parser[String] = """::="""

  def epsilon: Parser[String] = "ε"

  def terminal: Parser[String] = "\"[^\"]+\"".r

  def sequence: Parser[String] =
    exp ~ exp ^^ { case left ~ right => left + right }

  def alternation: Parser[String] =
    exp ~ "|" ~ exp ^^ { case left ~ _ ~ right => left + "|" + right }

  def opt: Parser[String] =
    "[" ~ exp ~ "]" ^^ { case lb ~ e ~ rb => lb + e + rb }

  def repetition: Parser[String] =
    "{" ~ exp ~ "}" ^^ { case lb ~ e ~ rb => lb + e + rb }

  def group: Parser[String] =
    "(" ~ exp ~ ")" ^^ { case lb ~ e ~ rb => lb + e + rb }

  def exp: Parser[String] =
    (epsilon
      | terminal
      | nonterminal
      | sequence
      | alternation
      | opt
      | repetition
      | group)

  def rule: Parser[String] = nonterminal ~ goesTo ~ exp ~ ";" ^^ {
    case nt ~ delim ~ e ~ semi => nt + delim + e + semi
  }

  def join[A](sep: String, list: Seq[A]): String = list match {
    case h :: t => h.toString() + t.foldLeft("")(_.toString() + sep + _.toString())
    case Nil => ""
  }

  def root: Parser[String] = phrase(
    rep(rule) ^^ {
      case rules =>
        val joined = join(" ;\n", rules)
        if (joined.isEmpty)
          joined
        else
          joined + " ;"
    }
  )

}

object Main extends App {
  val parser = new EbnfParserSimple()
  val grammar = """<A> ::= ["a"|ε]"c" ; """
// <B> ::= <A>"b" ;
// <C> ::= {<B>}"$" ;
// <D> ::= "a""b""d" ;
// <E> ::= ("a"|"b")"c" ;
// """
  val rule = parser.root
  println(parser.parse(rule, grammar))
}
```

#### Error Trace

Full log can be found [as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/benknoble/0197852b707c78619e45734e8bed9010).

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/Knoble/loner/project
[info] Loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to loner (in build file:/Users/Knoble/loner/)
[info] Set current project to ebnf (in build file:/Users/Knoble/loner/)
[info] Running org.benknoble.ebnf.Main 
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.StackOverflowError
[error] java.lang.StackOverflowError
[error]     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1673)
[error]     at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
[error]     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
[error]     at scala.util.matching.Regex.<init>(Regex.scala:226)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r(StringLike.scala:284)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r$(StringLike.scala:284)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.r(StringOps.scala:33)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r(StringLike.scala:273)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r$(StringLike.scala:273)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.r(StringOps.scala:33)
[error]     at org.benknoble.ebnf.EbnfParserSimple.terminal(EbnfParser_strings.scala:13)
[error]     at org.benknoble.ebnf.EbnfParserSimple.$anonfun$exp$1(EbnfParser_strings.scala:32)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser.p$lzycompute$1(Parsers.scala:253)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser.p$4(Parsers.scala:253)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser.$anonfun$append$2(Parsers.scala:254)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Failure.append(Parsers.scala:202)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser.$anonfun$append$1(Parsers.scala:254)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser.$anonfun$append$1(Parsers.scala:254)
[...]
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser.$anonfun$append$1(Parsers.scala:254)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser.$anonfun$append$1(Parsers.scala:254)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser.$anonfun$append$1(Parsers.scala:254)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser.$anonfun$append$1(Parsers.scala:254)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Parsers.scala:239)
[error]     at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 12 mars 2019 21:11:15
```

Comment: At a glance I'd guess you're running into the fact that `RegexParsers` can't accept left-recursive grammars. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48209998/334519) has some suggestions for how to rewrite your grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up being able to solve my problem by removing the left recursion via [techniques found in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48209998/334519). Below find the working code.

I had to think carefully about the transformations: particularly `alternation.+ ^^ { _.reduce(_ + _) }` and `sequence.+ ^^ { _.reduce(_ + _) }`—converting those back to the AST generator may be non-trivial (as the constructors for those require only a left and right). The repetition also bothers me a little, but without extracting a helper function it was the only thing to do.

```scala
package org.benknoble.ebnf

import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

class EbnfParserSimple extends RegexParsers {

  def epsilon: Parser[String] = "ε"

  def terminal: Parser[String] = "\"[^\"]+\"".r

  def nonterminal: Parser[String] = """<[^>]+>""".r

  def opt: Parser[String] =
    "[" ~ exp ~ "]" ^^ { case lb ~ e ~ rb => lb + e + rb }

  def repetition: Parser[String] =
    "{" ~ exp ~ "}" ^^ { case lb ~ e ~ rb => lb + e + rb }

  def group: Parser[String] =
    "(" ~ exp ~ ")" ^^ { case lb ~ e ~ rb => lb + e + rb }

  def alternation: Parser[String] =
    chainl1(epsilon
      | terminal
      | nonterminal
      | opt
      | repetition
      | group,
      "|" ^^^ { (lb: String, rb: String) => lb + "|" + rb })
  //   exp ~ "|" ~ exp ^^ { case left ~ _ ~ right => left + "|" + right }

  def sequence: Parser[String] =
    alternation.+ ^^ { _.reduce(_ + _) }
    // alternation ~ alternation ^^ { case lb ~ rb => lb + rb }
  //   exp ~ exp ^^ { case left ~ right => left + right }

  def exp: Parser[String] =
    sequence.+ ^^ { _.reduce(_ + _) }

  def goesTo: Parser[String] = """::="""

  def rule: Parser[String] = nonterminal ~ goesTo ~ exp ~ ";" ^^ {
    case nt ~ delim ~ e ~ semi => nt + delim + e + semi
  }

  def join[A](sep: String, list: Seq[A]): String = list match {
    case h :: t => h.toString() + t.foldLeft("")(_.toString() + sep + _.toString())
    case Nil => ""
  }

  def root: Parser[String] = phrase(
    rep(rule) ^^ {
      case rules =>
        val joined = join(" ;\n", rules)
        if (joined.isEmpty)
          joined
        else
          joined + " ;"
    }
  )

}

object Main extends App {
  val parser = new EbnfParserSimple()
  val grammar = """<A> ::= ["a"|ε]"c" ; """
// <B> ::= <A>"b" ;
// <C> ::= {<B>}"$" ;
// <D> ::= "a""b""d" ;
// <E> ::= ("a"|"b")"c" ;
// """
  val rule = parser.root
  println(parser.parse(rule, grammar))
}
```