# Scala Parser Combinator

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I am trying to write a Scala Parser combinator for the following input.

The input can be

- 10
- (10)
- ((10)))
- (((10)))

Here the number of brackets can keep on growing. but they should always match. So parsing should fail for `((((10)))`

The result of parsing should always be the number at the center

I wrote the following parser

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
class MyParser extends RegexParsers {
  def i = "[0-9]+".r ^^ (_.toInt)
  def n = "(" ~ i ~ ")" ^^ {case _ ~ b ~ _ => b.toInt}
  def expr = i | n
}
val parser = new MyParser
parser.parseAll(parser.expr, "10")
parser.parseAll(parser.expr, "(10)")
```

but now how do I handle the case where the number of brackets keep growing but matched?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy, just make the parser recursive:

```
class MyParser extends RegexParsers {
  def i = "[0-9]+".r ^^ (_.toInt)
  def expr: Parser[Int] = i | "(" ~ expr ~ ")" ^^ {case _ ~ b ~ _ => b.toInt}
}
```

(but note that scala-parser-combinators has trouble with *left*-recursive definitions: [Recursive definitions with scala-parser-combinators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207601/recursive-definitions-with-scala-parser-combinators))